# Extract n-decimal from string

Tags: regex, r

I've browsed half stackoverflow in search of this but nothing seems to perfectly match, sorry if wrong.

I've got a string with the format:

`fname <-'FS1_SCN0.83_axg3.csv'`

I'd like to extract the second number, which happens to be a decimal, but *could also be* an integer, and get as a result 0.83 (or 3 if integer). Closest I've got is this:

```
gsub("[^0-9.]","\\2",fname)
```

that produces all the numbers and decimal markers in fname (10.833.), but as a whole string.

Thanks in advance,      p.

Comment: Will it always be `letter<number_you_want>underscore`?

Comment: Yes, it will, I even know the specific characters. Happy to listen to your solution, but I thought generalising it would be more interesting for other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the second number,

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("^\\D*\\d+\\D*\\K\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?", x, perl=TRUE))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lK1hK2/1)

or

```
sub("^\\D*\\d+\\D*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
```

**Example:**

```
> x <-'FS1_SCN0.83_axg3.csv'
> regmatches(x, regexpr("^\\D*\\d+\\D*\\K\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?", x, perl=TRUE))
[1] "0.83"
> sub("^\\D*\\d+\\D*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "0.83"
```

For more general case,

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("^\\D*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\D*\\K\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?", x, perl=TRUE))
sub("^\\D*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\D*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
```

**OR**

Just specify the index number to get the number you want.

```
> regmatches(fname, gregexpr("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?", fname))[[1]][2]
[1] "0.83"
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Regex

```
.+_SCN(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)_.+\.csv
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dN7jV1/2)

#### Sample code

```
sub(".+_SCN(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)_.+\\.csv", "\\1", fname)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^.*?(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*?\\K\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?
```

You can use this `perl=True` option and grab the match.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/8

or

```
gsub("^.*?(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*$","\\1",fname,perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_extract_all()` from the `stringr` package for matching all numbers in the given input then grab the captured group #2 from resulting array:

```
library(stringr)

str_extract_all(fname, "([0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?)")
```

Comment: Thanks, seems the simplest solution proposed here, but not sure on how to extract the 2nd match from array?

Comment: You can do: `match = str_extract_all(fname, "([0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?)")` then `match[[2]]`

Comment: [Some example are of `str_extract_all` are here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing)

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, you could use this: `_[A-Z]+(\d+(\.\d+)?)` as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/lG0qS2/1). As a minor note, this proposed answer does not do anything that the ones posted do not. I just think that it is slightly more readable and easier to follow.

If you know the *exact* characters, it might make sense to replace the `[A-Z]` section with said characters. This would make the expression even more intuitive.